# Ubuntu 12.04 MAC change not able to connect - Broadcom BCM4313

Tags: wireless, network-manager, broadcom

Okay guys, so i've looked around extensively on this topic, only to find that no one has a true solution, only half explained work arounds. Something tells me this problem can be solved, for the pure reason that i " CAN " change my wifi-cards MAC address in windows 7 both manually and using Iron Geeks madMACS. So this leads me to investigate, why after changing my mac on ubuntu 10.04/10.10/12.04/Backtrack 5 r2/r3 why I can not connect.

Please note that this is not a problem of my router, I have tried it on multiple public access points, and with my changed MAC, I can not even connect to an open network. I've read somewhere that you have to change the mac before the wifi-card's true MAC is released in BIOS. Is this true? This is the only logical explanation I can think of right now.

I don't mind going out and buying a new wifi-card that does support ubuntu MAC cloning. If any one has one working out of the box please let me know.

> description: Wireless interface
>          product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
>
> ```
>    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>
>    physical id: 0
>
>    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>
>    logical name: wlan0
>
>    version: 01
>
>    serial: c0:18:85:43:c6:e4
>
>    width: 64 bits
>
>    clock: 33MHz
>
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=10.1.1.8 latency=0
>
>    link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 8 '
> ```

I have tried both Network-Manager & WICD both failing.

I use Acer Aspire D-270, first off i couldn't even change my MAC address, got the error of device busy etc. But then i added the macchange to startup now the mac changes but it just wont connect till i set it back to original mac.

Comment: Could it be, that you change the MAC address to something illegal? Can you post what you change it to, or the exact command you use.

Comment: I don't believe brcmsmac is the ideal driver for your device. Please run lspci -nn. Is the pci.id 14e4:4727? If so, I think the STA driver is correct. Having said that, I have no idea if you can change the MAC there either. You certainly can connect better. I doubt being able to connect has anything to do with the MAC and everything to do with the driver. Would you like to change the driver?

Comment: Mikewhatever - Hi Mike, I truly appreciate your good samaritan like behavior however it's comment's like this that tend to waste users time and effort. All that aside, i've tried both " sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx & i've also downloaded "macchanger" and added it to startup function yet still neither work.

Comment: Chili555 - Thankyou for your input Chilli, I can appreciate your sensibility and are very grateful you have offered to help.

I have tried to " run lspci-nn " & "lspci-nn" from terminal as ROOT. But it comes back "command not found".

I understand what your saying **"I doubt being able to connect has anything to do with the MAC and everything to do with the driver"**

However if the driver is the problem, Why can i connect "before" i change my MAC address. It's only 'After' i change my MAC is when i get no connectivity. But if you still think it's a driver issue im happy changing.

Comment: It is not lspci-nn. It is lspci  -nn. There is a space between lspci and -nn.

Comment: Is your chosen MAC address listed as reserved (for any purpose) at http://www.iana.org/assignments/ethernet-numbers/ethernet-numbers.xml ? (I guess that is what @mikewhatever meant with illegal)